# Index not used for query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I'm running the following query, and the index I have created is not used; PostgreSQL uses a sequential scan instead of an index scan.

Query:

```
EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers)
SELECT  date, 
    company, 
    host
FROM    mytable
where   date < ( now() - INTERVAL '10 days' )
```

The index I have created:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_mytable_company ON mytable USING btree (
    host,
    cumpany,
    date
)





thanks for the reply but i still have problems

get this no matter what i try:

Seq Scan on mytable (cost=0.00..5577644.22 rows=65056015 width=34) (actual time=120.238..43372.108 rows=63058234 loops=1) Filter: (date < (now() - '10 days'::interval)) Rows Removed by Filter: 2543550 Buffers: shared hit=581914 read=3847699 Planning Time: 1.263 ms JIT: Functions: 4 Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true Timing: Generation 0.495 ms, Inlining 66.265 ms, Optimization 37.358 ms, Emission 16.325 ms, Total 120.443 ms Execution Time: 46204.494 ms

view index shows this CREATE INDEX ix_mytable_company ON public.mytable USING btree (date) INCLUDE (host, cumpany)

and i still run: EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers) SELECT date,cumpany,host FROM mytable where date < (now() - INTERVAL '10 days' )

6.5 milj rows should qualify for an index scan i think.
```

Comment: Try to remove host and company from your index expression

Comment: Addition to @VasylMoskalov comment: How many rows in your table? If there are small number of rows the planner may choose to seq scan table because it's faster than 2 read operations: read from index and from table

Comment: Could you share the query plan as well?

Comment: @DmitryK. I think that the planner even will not try touse this index 'cause the date field is the last in the index definition. So, if where will be like 'host=val and cumpany=val1 and date<....) then, may be, index will be used.

Comment: @VasylMoskalov you're absolutely right

Comment: sorry for messing structure in this thread, im im not used to handle threads in this forum.
i guess Laurenz Albe comment summarize the issue
"That would mean that so many rows satisfy the condition that PostgreSQL decides to do a sequential scan." il try to narrow down all those same date answers
Its 6,5 milj rows not 65 milj

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `date` is not the first column in the index, so the index cannot be used for the query. It would be enough to have an index on `date` alone, but if you are targeting an index-only scan, you could use this index:

```
CREATE INDEX myindex ON mytable (date) INCLUDE (company, host);

/* for good performance, refresh the visibility map */
VACUUM mytable;
```

Note that an index will only be used if the table is big enough.

Comment: if i use 
where   date < ( now() - INTERVAL '10 days' ) -- sequential scan occur
where   date > ( now() - INTERVAL '10 days' ) -- indesx scan occur

what could explain this behavior, index sort order?

Comment: @wiper That would mean that so many rows satisfy the condition that PostgreSQL decides to do a sequential scan.